# Optional some special characters such as @, - or . in Django URL

Tags: django

I want to create a url that allow both user email and username in Django such as:

```
http://mysite.dev/profile/abc@somedomain.com
```

or

```
http://mysite.dev/profile/this-is-my-username
```

Both above must be allowed. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to match an url.
Here's a regex matching your two cases : `[\w\d@\.-]+`.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from youapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[\w\d@\.-]+)$', views.details, 'details')
]
```

Take a look at the Django documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request